# Is there any way to access automatically any Log in Logcat by a double click?

Tags: android, eclipse, line, logcat

Is there any way to access automatically any Log in Logcat by a double click ?

Actually, when there is an error crashing my Android Application, I can double click on the line saying for instance

```
at com.myapp.mypackage$Class.function(File.java:117)
```

And by Double-clicking on this line, I am automatically redirected to the related line of my code.

But, when I try to generate the same line in another Log, example :

```
Log.e("TAG", "at com.myapp.mypackage$Class.function(File.java:117)");
```

The Double-Click doesn't work anymore ...

Any ideas ?

Comment: You could probably `throw` an exception from the line where you get the issue.. But that would also stop your program

Comment: That's because the editor handles *Stack traces* from exceptions. Depending on the code from the editor, this is only possible if the creator of the IDE matches a string in the log to an actual file in your project.

Comment: If using eclipse, you can use the ["Stacktrace Console"](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fconsole%2Fref-stacktrace_console.htm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind the clutter in your log, you can easily just add a `new Exception()` to the log message

```
Log.e("TAG", "Looky here see", new Exception());
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, that's kind of efficient, and I really don't mind about cluttering my log.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to create a log in logcat that can be clicked and go to your line use the following method to create it:

Enjoy!

```
public static void showLogCat(String tag, String msg) {

        StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElement = Thread.currentThread()
                .getStackTrace();
        int currentIndex = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < stackTraceElement.length; i++) {
            if (stackTraceElement[i].getMethodName().compareTo("showLogCat") == 0)
            {
                currentIndex = i + 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        String fullClassName = stackTraceElement[currentIndex].getClassName();
        String className = fullClassName.substring(fullClassName
                .lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
        String methodName = stackTraceElement[currentIndex].getMethodName();
        String lineNumber = String
                .valueOf(stackTraceElement[currentIndex].getLineNumber());

        Log.i(tag, msg);
        Log.i(tag + " position", "at " + fullClassName + "." + methodName + "("
                + className + ".java:" + lineNumber + ")");

    }
```