# Eclipse not opening source when click in logcat

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

Until recently I could double-click a line in stack-trace the logcat and it would open the source at that point.
Suddenly it has stopped working.

Is it possible that I accidentley changed some option somewhere?
What could I have done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it.

In the project Properties->Java Build Path->Order and Export the src folder of the library had to be selected. For some reason it wasn't.

Works great now.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know about the option, but I can tell you that I've experienced that (and other) particularity with logcat without touching anything in the configs. What I do is make sure that log output is not paused (the little "||" button in logcat console) and if it is I unapuse it in order to let me double click on an entry and have it highlight the corresponding code. Also you may try adding then removing some filters in order to force it come back to life. I know it's lame but from what I've seen it has such issues.

Comment: Tried your idea but still the same.

Comment: I found it. In the project Properties->java Buil Path->Oder and Export the src folder of the library had to be selected. For some reason it wasn't. Works great now.

Comment: @theblitz - You should consider adding the above comment as an answer.  Then you can select it as the solution and it will be easier for others to find.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12242852/779408) that creates a log that opens your log position when you click on the row in logcat.

Enjoy!

Comment: he was asking to open source file when he double-clicks a line in stack-trace the logcat.. your answer is irrelevant.

Comment: @MuhammadIrfan lines in LogCat that are clickable have format like this `at org.test.order.ui.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:109)` that I have created in that answer.

Comment: I do not understand still why developer needs to create it, it is sometthing provided by eclipse itself ??

Comment: @breceivemail offer the way so one can create this linkable logcat lines. I have just implement in Android Studio 1.5 and its work perfect.

Comment: @MuhammadIrfan - Have you check the link? Its offer more than provided by Eclipse and Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen when I cloned a new project from an old project and then ran the new project.  Apparently Eclipsed was confused by there being two files with the same path and name in two different open projects in the same workspace.  When I closed the old project, it return to switching perspectives and taking me to the line of code when I double clicked the line in logcat.