# How can I create Android logcat entries that provide a link to source code in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any way to access automatically any Log in Logcat by a double click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8067528/is-there-any-way-to-access-automatically-any-log-in-logcat-by-a-double-click)

If a warning or error stack trace is printed to the `logcat` in `Eclipse` from an `Android` application, I have the ability to double click a line of it to see where in the source code this line of the stack trace is discussing. Is there a way, through the Android or Eclipse SDKs, to print my own messages with links to the code?

Comment: how about the solutions found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8067528/is-there-any-way-to-access-automatically-any-log-in-logcat-by-a-double-click/12242852#12242852