# How to make logcat clickable?

Tags: android, logcat

Now in my app, i use custom log for show only Debug.

and I saw a blog about make link to click logcat line and it go to that line.

```
private static String tag() {
        StackTraceElement trace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[4];
        String fileName = trace.getFileName();
        String classPath = trace.getClassName();
        String className = classPath.substring(classPath.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
        String methodName = trace.getMethodName();
        int lineNumber = trace.getLineNumber();
        return TAG + "# " + className + "." + methodName + "(" + fileName + ":" + lineNumber + ")";
    }
```

now it show in logcat,

[image]

:68 and :195 is line Number. it is almost working. but, i can't click and go to code.

How I can solve this?

Comment: I believe this answer would help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12242852/1922461

Comment: in my case this link in not working T.T  anyway thanks for your comment

Comment: Im not sure but check it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115008/how-can-we-print-line-numbers-to-the-log-in-java/4332163#4332163